# POS System with Pos for .NET

Tags: pos-for-.net

I am planning on creating my own POS system by using pos for .net.
So far i have never created any POS system or used pos for .net. I was trying to find some tutorials but wasn't successfull, does anybody know some good website or book? I am also wondering if there is a way to emulate the pos devices (like barcode scanner....)

Comment: I too am building a POS system and found documentation and sample code on the internet lacking a bit.  Also, looks like POS for .Net is no longer being supported by MS. Am currently digging through epsonexpert.com site for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Using [windows embedded 8 industry](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/windows-embedded-8-industry.aspx) 
As your base system and the POS .net you will be able to achieve what you are trying to do. 

As mentioned by @CResults most barcode readers are plug and play. So unless they need to have com ports mapped you will not have to do anything to them. They scan decode and then send the values like a keyboard
Receipt printers are the issue. You can either use the windows driver to print to the printer (highly buggy) or every receipt printer you can communicate directly too through a Com port. You will need to ask for the SDK from the manufacture. This way you are communicating direct to the printer rather then relying a mediator that could crash or freeze. 
But the time you are going to spend building your project there are plenty of already created ones. It would be worth while to use a system that has already been developed on for years. Rather then re-invent the wheel.


Check out Bepoz http://bepoz.com/ They have been around for a while and have a very solid application.

Disclaimer: Employee of Bepoz

Answer (score 1):

I believe the SDK comes with plenty of sample code and documentation.

There's also a community forum:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/posfordotnet/threads

Comment: I read quickly through SKD documentation and I am not sure I got the main idea. The service object of the specific POS device is provided by POS device vendor or it's already part of POS for .Net??

Answer (score 0):

To answer part of your question most barcode scanners appear to the OS as keyboards, sending their output (the decoded value of the barcode) to your app as a string of characters.

So to emulate all you need do is capture the keyboard.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, i would expect there is an emulation tool to simulate pos devices the simulate the communication with the pos application, am I wrong?

Comment: If you're creating a POS system I wouldn't worry about your input/output devices from day 1. You need to consider other things such as stock control, pricing, user interface, database structure, security, reporting....